# How to Create Searchable Text Box For Long List Selector in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Please Help to Reproduce .. to Searchable Long List Selector.

How to Create Searchable Text Box For Long List Selector in Windows Phone 8 Platform .

any help is appreciated

thanks in advance.

Comment: Autocomplete box or just search box?

Comment: Just a Searchable Text Box Not a Autocomplete Box

Comment: So, what is your problem? You don't know how to search in your long list selector with a search box?

Comment: What do you use for create your longlistselector?AlphaGroupeKey or others things?

Comment: NO, Just Searching For Countries List , displaying in a Long List Selector

Comment: You don't create group or something?

Comment: Am just Sorting.  List<AlphaKeyGroup<CountryInfo>> DataSource = AlphaKeyGroup<CountryInfo>.CreateGroups(CountryInfoList,
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture,
                (CountryInfo s) => { return s.Name; }, true);

Answer (score 0):

//View
So create TextBox and a button =>

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Width="200" Text="{Binding Text,Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
                <Button Command="{Binding Search}"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

//ViewModel

```
  private List<AlphaKeyGroup<CountryInfo>> _dataSource;

  public List<AlphaKeyGroup<CountryInfo>> DataSource
  {
    get { return _dataSource; }
    set
    {
       _dataSource= value;
       RaisePropertyChanged(() => DataSource);
    }
   }

  private string _searchText;

  public string SearchText
  {
     get { return _searchText; }
     set {
           _searchText= value;
           RaisePropertyChanged(() => SearchText);
          }
   }
    public RelayCommand Search {get;set;}
```

//Constructor

```
Search = new RelayCommand(setSearchList);
```

//Methode

```
    private void setSearchList(){

      if(string.isNullOrEmpty(SearchText)){
        DataSource = AlphaKeyGroup<CountryInfo>.CreateGroups(CountryInfoList,    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, (CountryInfo s) => { return s.Name; }, true);
      }else{
        var listCopy= CountryInfoList.where(item=> item.Name == SearchText).ToList();
         DataSource = AlphaKeyGroup<CountryInfo>.CreateGroups(listCopy, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, (CountryInfo s) => { return s.Name; }, true); }
    }
```

Your itemSource is the DataSource property.

Comment: It's from MVVM Light toolkit. If you don't use binding for your application, you can replace RelayCommand by a click event and remove the SearchText Property by yourTextbox.Text.

Comment: Yes, ok now i understand. can share any SAmple Source code with URL MVVMLight Concept for WP8 am New to that MVVM Light Plaform ... Can u Suggest ...

Comment: It's about WPF application but it's the same way.http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/